# Optimizing a recursive counting algorithm

Tags: c, algorithm, recursion

I hate posting for homework help on here, but I've exhausted my abilities. I am faced with a Stack Overflow (at least thats what its called in Java) issue while writing a simple recursive function in C.

I need every r-permutation of n numbers, and I figured the best way to do that would be counting in base n to length r.

It works fine for smaller amounts of numbers, but the highest case (n=10, r=6) ends up running out of memory. I could easily have written this iteratively but its required to be recursion. Heres what I have so far:

```
int permute(int *tempArray, int amtNums, int goalLength, int totalMatches) {
    totalMatches += 1; //Temporary, will be replaced by a function later

    printArray(tempArray, goalLength);

    tempArray[0]++;

    int j = 0;
    while(tempArray[j] >= amtNums) {
        tempArray[j+1]++;
        tempArray[j] = 0;
        j++;
    }

    if(j+1 > goalLength) return totalMatches;


    return permute(tempArray, amtNums, goalLength, totalMatches);
}
```

Being called as `permute((int*)calloc(numSlots, sizeof(int)), 10, 6, 0);` for the max case, n=10 r=6

I should Note: The counting isn't exactly intuitive, its a bit backwards but generates all the number combinations I wanted. As an example: n=4, r=3

```
0 0 0 
1 0 0 
2 0 0 
3 0 0 
0 1 0 
1 1 0 
2 1 0 
3 1 0 
.....
0 2 3 
1 2 3 
2 2 3 
3 2 3 
0 3 3 
1 3 3 
2 3 3 
3 3 3
```

Comment: Although this is not the cause of the stack overflow, never pass `calloc` as a parameter, you need to check his return.

Comment: @AlterMann I'm not actually passing calloc, I just put that so I didnt have to take up more space in the question, think of it as pseudo code

Comment: @gsamaras it works fine for smaller cases that don't require as much recursion

Comment: @Duck: Hint: your callstack should never be more than `n` deep.

Comment: @MooingDuck I know thats the optimal way to do this, I just am not sure how to go about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I belive that you have to modify your recursive function in order to have a maximum depth of the stack of function calls of `goalLength`. You can accomplish that adding a parameter `depth` like I did here:

```
int permute( int *tempArray, int amtNums, int goalLength, int depth, int totalMatches) {
    int i;

    if ( depth < goalLength - 1) {
        for ( i = 0; i < amtNums; ++i ) {
            tempArray[depth] = i;
            totalMatches = permute(tempArray, amtNums, goalLength, depth + 1, totalMatches);
        }
    } else {
        for ( i = 0; i < amtNums; ++i ) {
            tempArray[depth] = i;
            printArray(tempArray, goalLength);
            ++totalMatches;
        }
    }

    return totalMatches;
}
```

You can of course rewrite it putting the `for` loop outside and the `if` inside. I tryed that code with this little test program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define NDIGIT 4
#define NLENGTH 3

void printArray( int *temp, int size ) {
    int i;

    for ( i = 0; i < size; ++i ) {
        printf("%d ", temp[i]);
    }
    printf("\n"); 
}

int permute( int *tempArray, int amtNums, int goalLength, int depth, int totalMatches);

int main(void) {
    int results[NLENGTH];
    int n = permute(results, NDIGIT, NLENGTH, 0, 0);

    printf("Total number of permutations: %d\n", n);

    return 0;
}
```

Setting `NDIGIT` to `10`, `NLENGTH` to `6` and commenting out the printing function (you can keep it if you want...) the program run fine and the output was:

```
Total number of permutations: 1000000
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function uses a tail call to itself, the compiler should be able to turn this recursion into a loop.  Enable optimisations with command line option `-O3` or whatever your IDE provides.  If the compiler implements the recursion, the function will recurse **amtNums<sup>goalLength</sup>**, which is a large number for n=10 and r=6: **1 000 000** recursion levels likely causes a **Stack Overflow**

Comment: That sounds like a cheap workaround that I don't want to use. I want to actually optimize this to work on any system without the `-03`

Comment: Do not recurse for each step, figure a way to only recurse when you need to flip the next digit.

Comment: I didnt know the best way to describe it, I might mentally have r and n flipped, max runtime should be 10^6 not 6^10. See my edit to the original question for an example of what I'm trying to do with length 3, amt of numbers 4

Comment: That could work. Hopefully that will be "recursive" enough. Personally I find it stupid to require recursion for tasks that shouldn't be done recursively.

Comment: I fixed the answer, recursing 1 million times is still probably too much: between 20 and 28 MB depending on the architecture.

Comment: Im making it to an average of 170k recursive calls on the stack before I run out of memory. Using ~16MB (xcode is great)

Comment: I agree about recursion, be I'm not sure you have the proper algorithm.

Comment: I most likely don't. This is my 3rd iteration of the algorithm from scratch. I'm going to try rewriting it with less recursion, maybe only recursion for flipping over the numbers